# Installing torch with GPU support but without downloading 3 GB of duplicated siloed CUDA libraries?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, gpu

I'm trying to make CUDA containers for DNN less heavy. PyTorch goes against my efforts, as it seems to come bundled with its own siloed copy of a large subset of CUDA libraries. But what if we have them already (possibly newer) and want to install just `torch`?

And bonus question: why cannot PyTorch detect or accept your system CUDA which matches its declared major and minor version (e.g. 1.8)? Why does it have to download its own hard-coded 1.8.x when your system has 1.8.y and y>x? After all, `tensorflow` can accept minor differences in CUDA builds, and avoid unwanted duplication of these heavy dependencies (measured in gigabytes).

---

A more concrete illustration of the problem

*(run under the reasonably new GPU driver - supporting the latest CUDA 12.2 - and the official `nvidia/cuda-11.8-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04:latest` container with CUDA 11.8.0 installed inside)*:

```
!nvidia-smi
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.104.05             Driver Version: 535.104.05   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
[..]
```

```
!env | grep CU | sort
CUDA_VERSION=11.8.0
[..]
NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION=11.8.0-1
[..]
NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE=libcudnn8=8.9.0.131-1+cuda11.8
NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV=libcudnn8-dev=8.9.0.131-1+cuda11.8
[..]
NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION=11.11.3.6-1
[..]
NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION=11.11.3.6-1
NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION=11.7.5.86-1
NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION=11.7.5.86-1
```

If you just intuitively try to install `pip install torch`, it will not download CUDA itself, but it will download the remaining NVIDIA libraries: its own (older) cuDNN (0.5 GB) and (older) NCCL, as well as various `cu11*` packages, including CUDA runtime (for an older version of CUDA - 11.7 instead of 11.8):

```
!pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Downloading torch-2.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (619.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 619.9/619.9 MB 5.3 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:02
[..]
Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
  Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu11-8.5.0.96-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (557.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 557.1/557.1 MB 5.1 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:02
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
  Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu11-10.9.0.58-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (168.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 168.4/168.4 MB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:01
Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1
  Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu11-11.4.0.1-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (102.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 102.6/102.6 MB 9.7 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:01
[..]
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66
  Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu11-11.10.3.66-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (317.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 317.1/317.1 MB 7.2 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:01
Collecting nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91
  Downloading nvidia_curand_cu11-10.2.10.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (54.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 54.6/54.6 MB 10.2 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:01
[..]
Collecting nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.14.3
  Downloading nvidia_nccl_cu11-2.14.3-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (177.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 177.1/177.1 MB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:01
Collecting nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu11-11.7.101-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 11.8/11.8 MB 11.4 MB/s eta 0:00:0000:0100:01
[..]
Collecting nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91
  Downloading nvidia_nvtx_cu11-11.7.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (98 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 98.6/98.6 KB 10.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu11-11.7.99-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (849 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 849.3/849.3 KB 11.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00a 0:00:01
[..]
Successfully installed cmake-3.27.5 filelock-3.12.4 lit-17.0.1 mpmath-1.3.0 networkx-3.1 nvidia-cublas-cu11-11.10.3.66 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11-11.7.101 nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11-11.7.99 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11-11.7.99 nvidia-cudnn-cu11-8.5.0.96 nvidia-cufft-cu11-10.9.0.58 nvidia-curand-cu11-10.2.10.91 nvidia-cusolver-cu11-11.4.0.1 nvidia-cusparse-cu11-11.7.4.91 nvidia-nccl-cu11-2.14.3 nvidia-nvtx-cu11-11.7.91 sympy-1.12 torch-2.0.1 triton-2.0.0
```

But if you try to install `torch` for CUDA 11.8 (specifying `--index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118`), then `torch` will make `pip` download it's own CUDA 11.8 bundle (2.3 GB, nearly 4 times larger than the `torch` wheel alone), probably not even checking if one is already installed (and available e.g. for `tensorflow`):

```
!pip install torch --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
Collecting torch
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118/torch-2.0.1%2Bcu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl (2267.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.3/2.3 GB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00:00:0100:06
[..]
Installing collected packages: mpmath, lit, cmake, sympy, networkx, filelock, triton, torch
Successfully installed cmake-3.25.0 filelock-3.9.0 lit-15.0.7 mpmath-1.3.0 networkx-3.0 sympy-1.12 torch-2.0.1+cu118 triton-2.0.0
```

So what was inside `torch-2.0.1%2Bcu118-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl`? We have some 3 GB (unpacked) of goodies there: cuDNN and several dynamic libraries with "cu" in their names, including the biggest one called `libtorch_cuda.so`, which - judging by its name and the sheer size - is PyTorch's own distribution of CUDA (or just a subset?):

```
148K    libcudnn.so.8
680K    libcudart-d0da41ae.so.11.0
1.3M    libc10_cuda.so
72M     libcudnn_ops_train.so.8
91M     libcublas.so.11
94M     libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8
98M     libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8
116M    libcudnn_adv_train.so.8
125M    libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8
241M    libtorch_cuda_linalg.so
548M    libcublasLt.so.11
621M    libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8
1.3G    libtorch_cuda.so
```

So it seems we don't need to install CUDA if it's PyTorch alone we are after, as it will download its own. Unless we make `torch` notice the pre-installed CUDA and cuDNN, the duplication of these libraries is unavoidable in other scenarios, because we will need the official NVIDIA version for the remaining DNN packages, such as Tensorflow or Hugging Face `transformers`.

Note: adding `--no-deps` argument to `pip install` would miss even the required C++ dynamic libraries (not just the bundled CUDA).

Comment: Even if you depend purely on the pytorch installer, AFAIK it does not install a GPU driver.  So if you already have an appropriate driver installed, great.  If not, there will likely be something to download, in addition to pytorch.

Comment: GPU driver's presence is never checked by pip during installation. It is perhaps not intuitive, but GPU-enabled containers can be built on CPU-only nodes /the cheapest VMs/ and work correctly when deployed on GPU-enabled hosts - only then the driver is used (and must be exposed from the host to the containerized system, not installed in the latter). So whether the build server has an appropriate driver installed when `pip install` is run has no relevance to downloading CUDA again (twice), sorry.

Comment: This question is all about CUDA and PyTorch, in equal measure, so sweeping under the carpet the `cuda` tag does not make sense IMHO. Anyway, it won't affect how Search engines index it (and they will bring the affected people anyway, so it was a bit of a wasted effort talonmies, you should have edited the question body too, e.g. to CUDA-niewidy:).

Comment: In anticipation of any closing attempts - If violating the DRY principle and creating avoidable bloat of a few gigabytes (!) per user is not a question about programming, then I don't know what is:)

Comment: This siloed cloning of dependencies has also security implications. I've just privately reported a critical vulnerability to maintainers of a Github project with 60k stars, caused by their bundling with their popular app of a vulnerable version of `node`. Luckily the siloed `node` clone is identical to the system-wide one, so it can be overwritten by a clean replacement to patch the container.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for a (better) answer to this question. In the meantime I have a solution that seems to work. If you use PDM for your project's dependency management, you can tell its dependency resolver to specifically ignore certain packages. For torch 2.2.1 w/ cuda12, you can add the following to your pyproject.toml:

```ini
[tool.pdm.resolution]
# Don't let PDM install all these runtime libraries -- they add GB's of bloat!
excludes = [
  "nvidia-cublas-cu12",
  "nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12",
  "nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12",
  "nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12",
  "nvidia-cudnn-cu12",
  "nvidia-cufft-cu12",
  "nvidia-curand-cu12",
  "nvidia-cusolver-cu12",
  "nvidia-cusparse-cu12",
  "nvidia-nccl-cu12",
  "nvidia-nvtx-cu12",
  "triton",
]
```

Then if you run `pdm add torch==2.2.1`, it will install the cuda version of pytorch but without installing the several GB of drivers. This is especially useful when installing your software into the official pytorch/cuda docker image, which already has all these libraries present.

Unfortunately, this makes it somewhat awkward if you actually do want to install these deps in certain environments that don't already have nvidia libraries installed. A workaround is to directly add an optional dependency group that forces these each to be installed. The exclude list above applies only for "implied" dependencies, not top-level dependencies of your project. So you can do:

```bash
pdm add -G cuda nvidia-cublas-cu12 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12 ...
```

then to force the nvidia libraries to install, you run `pdm install -G cuda`.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch publishes the installation process for a CPU-only version of their Python package on [their getting started page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). It looks like they just publish it on a different python package index.

Assuming you're on Linux x64, the download would be the command to install the package with pip. There are several other options on the linked page.

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```

Comment: I don't think the question is about installing a CPU-only version.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for any ambiguity, I will rephrase the title by adding "with GPU support".